# Applet didn't work in browser

Tags: java, eclipse, japplet

My applet didn't work in browser.
When i try to open this html in firefox, i saw `"ClassNotFOundException, applet.NotHelloWord.class"`
I spent too much time with this useless application

My NotHelloWord.class is in `workspaceEclipse/FirstApplet/bin/applet/NotHelloWord.class`

My NotHelloWord.html is in `workspaceEclipse/FirstApplet/bin/NotHelloWord.html`

In my `NotHelloWord.html` i put:

```
<html>

<body>

<applet code="applet.NotHelloWord.class" codebase="Applet" width="300" height="300"> 
</applet>

</body>

</html>
```

My NotHelloWord.java:

```
package applet;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class NotHelloWord extends JApplet {

    public void init()
    {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {

                JLabel label = new JLabel("FirstApplet", SwingConstants.CENTER);
                add(label);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Applets are basically dead and shouldn't be used.

Comment: yes, but my school still want this from me :/

Comment: We have *got* to get a canonical "fix your curriculum" post here. Applets are *dead*. They won't work in your browsers because *the browsers no longer support them*. This isn't an issue of "it's a bad idea to do this", it's an issue of "the technical capability no longer exists".

Comment: you are wrong, it has just repaired

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 2) @chrylis We have one in a blog. OP, please refer the teacher to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, but that's more about the "it's better to start with simpler pieces and build" side than the "all support has been removed and you Just Can't Do It" side.

Comment: @chrylis Yeah, I wrote it before the ability to embed applets completely vanished. But given the other two links about the plug-in being phased out, I really could not be bothered revisiting it in a blog just on that.